# Python program gets deadlock

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x, deadlock

My program gets deadlock after working about a half hour. I use global thread safe queue `usernamesQueue = Queue()`, main thread produces items to queue and wait for handling them:

```
while(True):
    print('processing file...')  

    with open('usernames') as f:
        for line in f:
            usernamesQueue.put(line.strip())

    usernamesQueue.join()
```

I start another threads like this:

```
for i in range(NUMBER_OF_WORKERS):
    threading.Thread(target=worker).start()
```

And handle values in queue like this:

```
def worker():
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)

        item = None

        item = usernamesQueue.get()

        if item is not None:
            processUser(item)

            usernamesQueue.task_done()
            time.sleep(random.randint(1, 5))
```

processUser catch any exception that can be thrown and sure there weren't exceptions before deadlock. What's wrong?

Comment: It's likely your `Queue` get to be full. In general it's a bad Idea to `put/get` large Data over a `Queue!

Comment: Hmm, It seems that the problem was in the HTTPSConnection which was waiting forever for response from server

Comment: @stovfl, What do you mean when say large data? How many bytes is it? And why I shouldn't use put/get with large data?

Comment: Consider the Data flow: Provider Read Line > Put Queue > Pickle Data > Write to OS Queue (Depends of Size and underlying OS leads to write to a File) > Get Queue > Read from OS Queue (Wich could be a File) > Depickle Data > Assign to Worker Variable. TO MUCH OVERHEAD!

Comment: @stovfl, I didn't know it. I think with unicode strings less than 30 symbols it wouldn't be much overhead. Is there any python analogue of this https://github.com/DevAlone/RealEngine/blob/master/src/engine/ThreadSafeQueue.hpp ? This is thread safe wrapper of std::queue which works in memory and uses mutex for synchronization

Comment: Never seen a Python Code using `Lock()` in conjunction with `Queue`, so I assume it's used by Default but can't recall this piece of knowledge yet. I agree 30 Symbols can't be considered as _large_.

Answer (score 0):

There weren't problems with deadlock, it was in HTTPSConnection which by default doesn't have timeout or have very big, I added timeout 15 seconds and program works fine even when server doesn't want to respond.